# what can you do with hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar?

Tags: hadoop

I am new to Hadoop and would like to understand the jar files that come with the installation.

I have been running the wordcount test using the hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar.  Things are going great but I want to know what else I can do with this jar file or other jar files available besides the wordcount?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the list of example programs by running:

```
hadoop jar /path/to/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar
```

My output:

```
Valid program names are:
aggregatewordcount: An Aggregate based map/reduce program that counts the words in the input files.
aggregatewordhist: An Aggregate based map/reduce program that computes the histogram of the words in the input files.
dbcount: An example job that count the pageview counts from a database.
grep: A map/reduce program that counts the matches of a regex in the input.
join: A job that effects a join over sorted, equally partitioned datasets
multifilewc: A job that counts words from several files.
pentomino: A map/reduce tile laying program to find solutions to pentomino problems.
pi: A map/reduce program that estimates Pi using monte-carlo method.
randomtextwriter: A map/reduce program that writes 10GB of random textual data per node.
randomwriter: A map/reduce program that writes 10GB of random data per node.
secondarysort: An example defining a secondary sort to the reduce.
sleep: A job that sleeps at each map and reduce task.
sort: A map/reduce program that sorts the data written by the random writer.
sudoku: A sudoku solver.
teragen: Generate data for the terasort
terasort: Run the terasort
teravalidate: Checking results of terasort
wordcount: A map/reduce program that counts the words in the input files.
```

Comment: @Jeremy Beard: where can i get complete information of these programs(like code, arguments needed for running ex. _wordcount_ _path/to/input_ _path/to/output_)

Comment: this works only after adding to conf/hadoop-env.sh: export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME:$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME:$HADOOP_YARN_HOME:$HADOOP_HOME:$HADOOP_CONF_DIR:$YARN_CONF_DIR:$JSVC_HOME